# How to ping many IPs in a file, and print only the online ones in another file using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ping

I have a file contaning a lot of ips, and I'd like to loop over them, ping them, and print to another file the one that is online. I know loop over file, ping them, but I dont know how to read output to know if the ip is online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this script

```
1. File full of IP's
[root@localhost scripts]# cat iplist.txt
172.31.57.63
localhost
127.0.0.1
172.31.57.62

2. Create the script

 [root@localhost scripts]# cat pingips.sh
 #!/bin/bash

 up_ipfile='online_server.txt'

 while IFS= read -r ips; do
        ping -c 1 $ips > /dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
              echo $ips >> $up_ipfile
        fi
 done < iplist.txt

 3. Run the script after making it executable 
 [root@localhost scripts]# ./pingips.sh


 4. It will create a file with IP's which are alive
 [root@localhost scripts]# cat online_server.txt
 172.31.57.63
 localhost
 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I execute this script, but it dont give me any output in terminal neither online_server file. Is there any error?

Comment: No, there are not any errors. It will not give any output as I am sending the output  and error of ping in /dev/null. But if your IP's are alive(pingable) then it will definitely be in online_server.txt. Can you make sure the IP's that you are testing are alive?

Comment: Oh, didnot know about that output was been sending to /dev/null, I am new on this sintax. In the file iplist.txt there are also many ips offline. @manishr

Comment: Ok, your answer really helpme, thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

You could use `nmap` for that:

`cat queryips.txt`

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.20.7
10.2.4.6
google.com
```

`nmap -iL queryips.txt -sn -n -oG upips.txt`

- `-iL queryips.txt` load host list from `queryips.txt` file
- `-sn` perform ping scan
- `-n` don't do reverse DNS lookup
- `-oG upips.txt` produce grepable ouptut into `upips.txt` file

`cat upips.txt`

```
# Nmap 6.47 scan initiated Thu Dec 31 12:12:27 2015 as: nmap -iL queryips.txt -sn -n -oG upips.txt
Host: 192.168.1.1 ()    Status: Up
Host: 192.168.20.7 ()   Status: Up
Host: 173.194.116.72 () Status: Up
# Nmap done at Thu Dec 31 12:12:28 2015 -- 4 IP addresses (3 hosts up) scanned in 1.26 seconds
```

Or to print the hosts that are up to stdout:

```
nmap -iL queryips.txt -sn -n -oG - | awk -F" " '!/#/ {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check the exit status of ping command.
`if ping ...; then echo online; fi`

Please note that you will have to restrict ping time using `-c` and `-w` flags.